# SQL query in session

Tags: cakephp, session

i want to develop search system in my cakephp application, by adding extra functionality in controller, and it works fine.

as you probably guess, after search and viewing record, when i return to index (list) page, i have all results from proper model, and search result is "forgotten".

so i guess that i have to keep my sql query in some sort of php session. can you help me how to manage that.

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to cache the last search results of a session? Could you store the result set in the session variable? One could also think about temporary tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cache::write](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1513/Cache-write), [Cache::read](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1512/Cache-read) and [Cache::set](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1516/Cache-set) (if necessary).

> Cache::write() can store any type of
>   object and is ideal for storing
>   results of model finds

Answer (score 0):

This is not so much a SQL problem as it is a CakePhp problem. There is a  component that handles what you are looking for.

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/pagination-recall

http://github.com/mcurry/pagination_recall